# Pass a container of smart pointer as argument in C++

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a function like below

```
void functionA(unordered_map<string, classA*>* arg1);
```

I need to pass in

```
unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<classA>>
```

How could I pass in the container with shared_ptr to the function which takes in a container of raw pointer? I am using C++0x here.

Thanks

Comment: Are you in control of the definition of `functionA`?

Comment: Hi Fred, I could possibly define another functionB which takes in the unordered_map with shared_ptr. However, I still need the functionA and how could I avoid code duplication over here as both of the functions will be doing the same thing and the only difference is in the prototype?

Comment: One thought I had was making `functionA` a template, so you could pass whatever kind of map fits the expected interface.

Comment: Thanks Fred. Could you roughly shows how would be the function prototype like for using the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked, here's what a template might look like for this function:

```
template <typename MAP_TYPE>
void functionA(const MAP_TYPE& arg1)
{
    // Use arg1 here
}
```

You could use a pointer and/or make it non-const if you must. As long as the map passed in uses a compatible key type and some kind of pointer to the right type as a value, it should compile and run. Whether the pointer is a native pointer or a smart pointer will likely not make a difference, depending on how you used it in your function implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Typewise `unordered_map<string, shared_ptr<classA>>` and `unordered_map<string, classA*>` are unrelated types.

So you can't directly pass one where the other is expected.

You can:

- change the signature of your function, or
- copy the data to an object of the expected type.

By the way, instead of a pointer argument, consider a reference argument.

Also, consider adding `const` wherever possible – it generally helps making the code easier to understand, because you then have guarantee of non-modification.

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to either modify functionA, or build a temporary unordered_map of the type that it wants to receive.